# Bash : Exclude range from array

Tags: bash, centos

I have an array from with numbers from 1 to 100:

```
array=$(seq 100)
```

My task is to exclude range from 60 to 80.

Comment: Are you sure it's an array? Seems more like a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion with the offset/length specification.

```
#! /bin/bash
arr=({1..100})
exclude_from=60
exclude_to=80
echo "${arr[@]:0:exclude_from-1}" "${arr[@]:exclude_to}"
```

Comment: I need to use loop in my task(

Comment: Why? This is much faster.

Comment: it is the condition of the task

Answer (score 1):

An arithmetic test condition

```sh
for n in {1..100}; do
    (( 60 <= n && n <= 80 )) && continue
    echo $n
done
```

However, to remove those elements from an array

```sh
ary=({1..100})
# note that number 1 is stored in _index_ 0
for ((n=60; n <= 80; n++)); do
    unset "ary[$((n-1))]"
done
declare -p ary
```

outputs

```sh
declare -a ary=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="6" [6]="7" [7]="8" [8]="9" [9]="10" [10]="11" [11]="12" [12]="13" [13]="14" [14]="15" [15]="16" [16]="17" [17]="18" [18]="19" [19]="20" [20]="21" [21]="22" [22]="23" [23]="24" [24]="25" [25]="26" [26]="27" [27]="28" [28]="29" [29]="30" [30]="31" [31]="32" [32]="33" [33]="34" [34]="35" [35]="36" [36]="37" [37]="38" [38]="39" [39]="40" [40]="41" [41]="42" [42]="43" [43]="44" [44]="45" [45]="46" [46]="47" [47]="48" [48]="49" [49]="50" [50]="51" [51]="52" [52]="53" [53]="54" [54]="55" [55]="56" [56]="57" [57]="58" [58]="59" [80]="81" [81]="82" [82]="83" [83]="84" [84]="85" [85]="86" [86]="87" [87]="88" [88]="89" [89]="90" [90]="91" [91]="92" [92]="93" [93]="94" [94]="95" [95]="96" [96]="97" [97]="98" [98]="99" [99]="100")
# ... note ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And

```sh
for n in "${ary[@]}"; do echo $n; done
# or more concisely
printf '%d\n' "${ary[@]}"
```

excludes 60-80

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=({1..100})
exclude=({60..80})

exclude_pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "@(${exclude[*]})")

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
  [[ $i == $exclude_pattern ]] && continue
  printf '%d\n' "$i"
done
```

---

Or create a temp array to build up the elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr=({1..100})
exclude=({60..80})

exclude_pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "@(${exclude[*]})")

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
  [[ $i == $exclude_pattern ]] && continue
  included_arr+=("$i")
done

arr=("${included_arr[@]}")

declare -p arr
```